Why is my batch script for handling an AWS upload failing?
I've written a batch script that:

Creates a filename based on today's date.
ZIPs a folder of files.
Creates a folder in my AWS bucket (if needed).
Uploads the ZIP.

Here's what I have:
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set zipstr=D:\Daily\fms25_daily_%year%-%month%-%day%.zip
set folderstr=%year%-%month%-%day%

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %zipstr% 

# create the daily folder if necessary
aws s3api put-object --bucket fmsbackupslts --key %folderstr%/ --content-length 0

# upload to S3
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<<MY ID>>
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<<MY KEY>>
set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
aws s3 sync %zipstr% s3://<<MY BUCKET>>/%folderstr%/

I get an error telling me that the file doesn't exist, but I know that it's being created properly.

Can you edit the question to include the exact text of the error message? That might help to identify the issue.

@echo off & setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0" :: Or point to the folder 
              :: where the executable is:
              :: cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\asw.exe"

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set "_mm=%%~j"
     set "_dd=%%~k"
     set "_yr=%%~l"
)

set "_zipstr=D:\Daily\fms25_daily_%_yr%-%_mm%-%_dd%.zip"
set "_folderstr=%_yr%-%_mm%-%_dd%"

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%_zipstr%"

# create the daily folder if necessary
aws s3api put-object --bucket fmsbackupslts --key "%_folderstr%/" --content-length 0

# upload to S3
set "_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<<MY ID>>"
set "_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<<MY KEY>>"
set "_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2"
aws s3 sync %_zipstr% s3://"<<MY BUCKET>>/%_folderstr%/"


Without knowing which characters are used in the definition or if any require escaping, I believe the most likely cause is to always prioritize preventing unpredictable behavior by ensuring predictable outcomes through the use of double quotes. As a best practice when defining variables, the resulting code would follow the proposal above, ensuring both clarity and protection against unexpected behaviors.
By using this updated version and encountering an error, substituting @echo off with @echo on can help reveal the line or command where the current error occurs. In that case, an additional edit to your inquiry can aid in providing a more precise corrective action, ensuring that debugging is both accurate and efficient.
Note: Obviously I have no way of reproducing the exact same scenario with the exact same elements, and I am not aware of what values ​​are being set in your variables and also call your script on the command line with 2>&1 Script.bat or if applicable, 2>&1 Script.cmd.

Alternative option considering the firm and reliable predictability of the date output layout regardless of region, language, user settings etc.
@echo off & setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0" :: Or point to the folder 
              :: where the executable is:
              :: cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\asw.exe"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%G in =;(`
     call "%%__AppDir__%%wbem\wmic.exe" OS Get LocalDateTime /Format:xml ^| "%%__AppDir__%%find.exe" "VALUE"
   `);= do set "_dt=%%~G"

set "_folderstr=%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~4,2%-%_dt:~6,2%"
set "_zipstr=D:\Daily\fms25_daily_%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~4,2%-%_dt:~6,2%.zip"

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%_zipstr%"

:# create the daily folder if necessary
aws s3api put-object --bucket fmsbackupslts --key "%_folderstr%/" --content-length 0

:# upload to S3
set "_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<<MY ID>>"
set "_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<<MY KEY>>"
set "_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2"

aws s3 sync %_zipstr% s3://"<<MY BUCKET>>/%_folderstr%/"
"%WinDir%\System32\timeout.exe" -1 | endlocal & goto :eof


Constructing the value of the _dt variable using the variable indexes:
@echo off

...

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%G in =;(`
     call "%%__AppDir__%%Wbem\Wmic.exe" OS Get LocalDateTime /Format:xml ^| "%%__AppDir__%%find.exe" "VALUE"
   `);= do set "_dt=%%~G" %=> 20240928221559 current date time < =%

Indexing substrings of variables/values using set _var=%_dt:~from-to% indexes:
 variables  |  substrings | refers  |  values    | indexes  
  set  _yr  =  %_dt:~0,4%   Year       2024        ~0,4
  set  _mm  =  %_dt:~4,2%   Month          09      ~4,2
  set  _dd  =  %_dt:~6,2%   Day              28    ~6,2
   
 set "_folderstr=%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~4,2%-%_dt:~6,2%"
 set "_zipstr=D:\Daily\fms25_daily_%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~4,2%-%_dt:~6,2%.zip"
...


Some further reading:

CD /?

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

Setlocal | Endlocal /?

Using: Commands with Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, 2>&1, etc.


What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com


